# Ошибка sql запроса

Tags: sql

> указаны слвпажаюище ключевые значения

Ошибка sql запроса, когда пытаюсь вставить запись в таблицу. Какие могут быть причины?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком просто было бы =) Вообще я разобрался, у пользователя не было прав писать в эту таблицу.

Answer (score 2):

> указаны слвпажаюище ключевые значения

Если я правильно вас понял, вы пытаетесь добавить строку со значением первичного ключа, которое уже есть в таблице. Т.е. так или иначе пытаетесь нарушить уникальность ключа. СУБД пытается сохранить целостность базы и не позволяет вам выполнить эту операцию.

Answer (score 1):

Понятно же написано, значит есть поле с уникальным ключом.

Comment: >слвпажаюище 
и как вам тут что то понятно, для меня, например, это слово - закадка :)

Comment: Для меня же стало загадкой слово "закадка" :)

Comment: @dem ну понять то можно, банальная опечатка, я вот реально не могу понять смысла слова "слвпажаюище"